# PANDAS count on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to tabulate a change in condition using a 'groupby' but am stumped and would appreciate any guidance. I have a data frame as follows:

```
SUBJECT    TYPE
1          1
1          2
1          2
2          1
2          1
3          1
3          3
3          5
```

I would like to generate a statement that tabulates any positive change, ignores any negative change, and generates a count of change per subject. For example, the output of the above would be:

```
Subject    TYPE
1          1
2          0
3          2
```

Would I need create an if/else clause using pandas, or is there a simpler way to achieve this using summit? Maybe something like...

```
def tabchange(type, subject):
    current_subject = subject[0]
    type_diff = type - type
    j = 1
    for i in range(1,len(type)):
        type_diff[i] = type[i] - type[i-j]
        if subject[i] == current_subject:
            if type_diff[i] > 0:
                new_row = 1
                j += 1
            else:
                j = 1
        else: 
            new_row[i] = 0
            current_subject = subject[i]
    return new_row
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual code?

Comment: .@AMS can you define what you mean by positive and negative  changes

Comment: A positive change would occur when the difference: row2 - row1 > 0; a negative change would result when the difference row2 - row1 < 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'SUBJECT': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
                   'TYPE': [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5]})
grouped = df.groupby('SUBJECT')
df['TYPE'] = grouped['TYPE'].diff() > 0
result = grouped['TYPE'].agg('sum')
```

yields

```
SUBJECT
1    1.0
2    0.0
3    2.0
Name: TYPE, dtype: float64
```

---

Above, `df` is grouped by `SUBJECT` and the diff is taken of the `TYPE` column:

```
In [253]: grouped = df.groupby('SUBJECT'); df['TYPE'] = grouped['TYPE'].diff() > 0 

In [254]: df
Out[254]: 
   SUBJECT   TYPE
0        1  False
1        1   True
2        1  False
3        2  False
4        2  False
5        3  False
6        3   True
7        3   True
```

Then, again grouping by `SUBJECT`, the result is obtained by counting the number of `True`s in the `TYPE` column:

```
In [255]: result = grouped['TYPE'].agg('sum'); result
Out[255]: 
SUBJECT
1    1.0
2    0.0
3    2.0
Name: TYPE, dtype: float64
```